# How can I center an image inside a TextView while using ImageGetter?

Tags: android, image, textview

Here's the meat of my ImageGetter, it seems to resize just fine inside the TextView however its always left aligned.  There have been some wonderful resources to get me where I am on [resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256955/scale-images-inside-textview-using-imagegetter) and also on handling [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424512/android-html-imagegetter-as-asynctask). The last hurdle I have seems pretty straight forward, is there a way to center the image inside the TextView?

```
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    if(source.matches("data:image.*base64.*")) {
        String base_64_source = source.replaceAll("data:image.*base64", "");
        byte[] data = Base64.decode(base_64_source, Base64.DEFAULT);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
        image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return image;
    } else {
        URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();
        ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = new ImageGetterAsyncTask(urlDrawable);
        asyncTask.execute(source);
        return urlDrawable; //return reference to URLDrawable where We will change with actual image from the src tag
    }
}

public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
    URLDrawable urlDrawable;

    public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
        this.urlDrawable = d;
    }

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
        String source = params[0];
        return fetchDrawable(source);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);//set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
        urlDrawable.drawable = result; //change the reference of the current drawable to the result from the HTTP call
        URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate(); //redraw the image by invalidating the container
        container.setText(container.getText());

    }

    public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
        try {

            DisplayMetrics metrics;
            new DisplayMetrics();
            metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(urlString).getContent();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable (context.getResources(), bmp);
            //Need logic here to calculate maximum width of image vs height so it doesnt strech
            int originalWidthScaled = (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * metrics.density);
            int originalHeightScaled = (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * metrics.density);
            if (originalWidthScaled > (metrics.widthPixels * 70) / 100) {
                width = (metrics.widthPixels * 70) / 100;

                height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * width
                        / drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            }else {
                height = originalHeightScaled;
                width = originalWidthScaled;
            }
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            return drawable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snipped code, This will help you to center the image by `Html.ImageGetter`.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        LevelListDrawable mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
        TextView textView = (TextView) params[2];
        BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(((Context)params[3]).getResources(),bitmap);
        mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);

        // [ Start : Centering the image by calculating Display width and Image width
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ((Context)params[3]).getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int totalGap = width - bitmap.getWidth()-120/*My Text view Padding*/;

        mDrawable.setBounds(totalGap/=2, 0, bitmap.getWidth()+totalGap, bitmap.getHeight());
        mDrawable.setLevel(1);
        // now image will show in center :End ]

        // i don't know yet a better way to refresh TextView
        // mTv.invalidate() doesn't work as expected
        CharSequence text = textView.getText();
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```